# Android data binding error with int attribute - <value>is incompatible with attribute <attribute_name> (attr) integer

Tags: java, android, xml, data-binding

i'm facing a problem trying to use data binding in my android app.
Long story short, I've created a custom view WPLView as follow:

```
public class WPLView extends LinearLayout {

    private String text;
    private int number;
    private Drawable drawable;

    public WPLView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        inflate(context, R.layout.wplview_layout, this);

        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                R.styleable.WPLView,
                0, 0);

        try {
            text = a.getString(R.styleable.WPLView_wplv_text);
            number = a.getInteger(R.styleable.WPLView_wplv_number, -1);
            drawable = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.WPLView_wplv_drawable);

            TextView tvText = findViewById(R.id.tv_text);
            tvText.setText(text);

            TextView tvNumber = findViewById(R.id.tv_number);
            tvNumber.setText(String.valueOf(number));

            tvNumber.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null, null);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

}
```

with its own stylable attributes:

```
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="WPLView">
        <attr name="wplv_text" format="string" />
        <attr name="wplv_number" format="integer" />
        <attr name="wplv_drawable" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

I've created an utility object for data binding like this:

```
public class MyObject{
    
    public int number;
    
    public MyObject(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    
}
```

and trying to use databinding like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />
        <variable name="obj" type="MyObject"/>
    </data>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="false" >

        ...
        
        <WPLView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:wplv_text="Losses"
                    app:wplv_drawable="@drawable/loss"
                    app:wplv_number="@{obj.number}"></WPLView>
        
        ...

    </ScrollView>
</layout>
```

but when i build my project I have this error:

AAPT: error: '@{obj.number}' is incompatible with attribute wplv_number (attr) integer.

What's the reason about it? I looked for it on web but I don't find a solution, I see always databinding for string attribute (like android:text) or similar but apparently nothing abount my case. Can you help me?